# How to exit Teamcity Build job without executing rest of build steps

Tags: teamcity

I have a Teamcity (v2020) build job that has 10 cmd line steps. However i wish to exit from this currently running job within step 2 itself - based on output of some command in step 2 i.e. i dont want steps 3 to 10 executed. - just like returning from a function in middle based on some if condition.

Conditional execution of build steps 3 to 10 - based on some Teamcity variable set in step 2 is not preferred solution.

Googling did not helped. exit call within job step exits that step only

Answer (score 0):

You can [fail](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-failure-conditions.html) your step (or build entirely) and set to following steps correspondent [Execution policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-build-steps.html#Execution+Policy)